# Blender gets stuck when switching to edit mode

Tags: interface, import

I plotted some surfaces in Mathematica and exported them as obj files. There are about 9,000 vertices and 14,000 faces (based on what is shown in the decimate modifier).

Blender will get stuck every time when I switch to the edit mode or unsubdivide with decimate. The UI has no response but Blender uses a lot of CPU, so it is actually frozen. I have tested the file on both Windows and Mac with Blender 3.6.4 and 3.3. I have tried to let it sit for a couple of hours, but it still behaves the same.
[image: UI freezes, but Blender uses 10-20% CPU in the background.]

Convert the obj file to stl or ply will work just fine. Loading the obj file with legacy loader is also fine, but some faces are missing. What is going on here?

Here is the Blender file. [image]

Comment: Crash confirmed. It seem there is an issue with the mesh that causes Blender to crash. I would suggest sending a bug report to Blender's developers to investigate further. To resolve the issue do the following: add a Weld Modifier to your model and apply it with the default settings. Now you can safely enter Edit mode.